# Ancient Civilization in non-Egyption Africa?

Tags: ancient-history, africa

I am looking for ancient civilizations in central and south of Africa. Were there any ancient cities, such as Timbuktu, Benin, or Zimbabwe for which there are scientific tools  or other artifacts giving evidence of early civilization?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what research you've attempted thus far? A simple web search for "ancient civilization" "southern Africa" yields millions of results.

Comment: can you place some stronger geographical boundaries on your question?

Comment: I have edited the question, and renominate it for opening in its present form.

Comment: @ihtkwot I mean all Africa expect Arab states.

Comment: @choster Wow! Can you please point out ten of millions of results?

Comment: @user1825 http://lmgtfy.com/?q="ancient+civilization"+"southern+Africa" . 2,050,000 results. At least a few of those should be useful.

Comment: "Were there any ancient cities, such as Timbuktu, Benin, or Zimbabwe for which there are scientific tools or other artifacts giving evidence of early civilization?" - Yes. Timbuktu, Benin and Great Zimbabwe, as a start. You answer your question in the question, making it unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Wow, people on this site can be deliberately obtuse. The question is asking about ancient civilizations in sub-saharan Africa, and it's an interesting one. Lots of medieval civilizations are well known, but less is known about earlier ones. Also, millions of results is almost worse than none at all - where do you begin? How do you begin? Study is more than plugging a search term into google. Another vote to re-open.

Comment: (1) is this a request for a list? (2) how can we distinguish between good answers and bad answers? (3) Is there any evidence of preliminary research? (4) what qualifies as "scientific tools"? (5) what qualifies as "early civilization"?  I think this is an *important* question, and an *interesting* question, I'm just not sure that it is a good H:SE question (yet).

Answer (score 4):

What's ancient for you?

- There are [old paintings in South Africa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_art)
- The [Kingdom of Kush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Kush) isn't in central/south of Africa, so I think it does not count.
- There is [Great Zimbabwe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Zimbabwe) (11th century)
- The [Mali Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mali_Empire) existed from 1230–c. 1600. This cultural heritage is actually a victim of war in Mali.

Wikipedia list some more Pre-Colonial African States in the article [History of Africa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Africa)

Comment: I think the Kingdom of Benin would also count as a kingdom more in the center of Africa.